# How to pass { history, location, match } when unit testing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am running tests against the following component:

```
const App: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history, location, match }) => { ... }
```

All the tests are passing however I get this warning:

```
const { getByText, debug } = render(<MemoryRouter><Route><App/></Route></MemoryRouter>);

Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, {}>': history, location, match(2739)
```

I was under the impression that `<MemoryRouter>` & `<Route>` would provide `<App/>` with the missing properties...

Comment: Can you try rendering the app with the base router and passing a custom history prop. Example `import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'; const history = createMemoryHistory();`  And render the app like this `render(<Router history={history}><App/></Router>)`. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Hmm not really; Still getting those warnings